# How to validate an unknown number of fields in a Laravel form

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I'm using Laravel 5.4, and have a form that's populated with questions from a database, with each question requiring a 'score' using radio buttons valued 1 thru 10. I need to accommodate an unknown number of questions, and I need validation to test that all questions have a score selected. All the radio button groups are are named q_ followed by the question_id (e.g. q_1, q_2, etc). I suppose this could all be done manually, but Laravel is such a powerful framework I have to think there's a "Laravel" way of doing this. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you avoid giving them prefixed names, and create an actual array using something like the following;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="question[{{ $question->id }}]" ...>
```

Now in your controller method you can just do;

```
$questions = $request->input('questions');
```

And your validator rules can look like the following;

```
$request->validate([
    'questions.*' => ['required', 'string']
]);
```

Laravel lets you validate arrays in many way, [check out the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays).

Comment: Holy smokes, I had no idea an array could be used for a checkbox input's name attribute. I've lived a far too sheltered life (and much more complicated as a result)! What threw me was your using question[] in the input attribute and then querying the $request with input('questions'). Was that a small typo on your part? Should it have been questions[] as the name attribute?
Awesome solution, THANKS!

Comment: Ahh yes @RobG, that was an error on my part. It should have been `$request->input('question')` though it'd be better if the field was called `questions[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at building a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-extensions) if you really want to use prefixes.  But I agree with ollieread, you should probably just handle all the questions as array elements.  To extend on that answer a little bit, here's what those rules would look like:

```
$rules = [
    'questions' => 'array',
    'questions.*.text' => 'required_with:questions|string',
    'questions.*.score' => 'required_with:questions|integer|min:1|max:10'
];
```

Comment: Together with your and ollieread's response, I'm pretty sure my question is completely answered. Thanks to y'all!

Answer (score -1):

You can use php and laravel to handle this. Suppose you get all the question Ids with a query in array.

```
$questionIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Than create an empty array to create the rules.

```
$validatedQuestionIds = [];
```

Now add the rules foreach the question Ids

```
foreach($questionIds as $key => $questionId){

    $validatedQuestionIds = [
       'q_'.$questionId = 'required|string';
    ];

}
```

And now validate the array using the laravel validate function.

```
$request->validate($validatedQuestionIds);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, a great lesson learned in putting together validation rules. In fact, I think I prefer your solution, thanks very much!